# C# WinForms and WebService Authentification

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, web-services

I've a problem communicating between a WinForms Application and a WebService.
At the beginning, the WebService haven't an simple Authentification :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.140).aspx

I've used exactly the same example, and that works well, between my WebSite and my WebService.

But between my WebService and my WinForms Application I've this error message :

```html
----------
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fService1.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

--------------
```

I don't really understand this error, but I'm almost sure I need to use an authorization method in my WinForms Application in order to consume WebMethods.

Do you know how ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: This is not an error message. But of course you need to authenticate if you want to call web service methods from winforms.

Comment: Hi Gert Arnold, do you have a tuto or something in order to learn what kind of method I need to use from WinForms ? Thanks for your answer of course ;) !

Comment: Do you have control of the WebService? If so take a look at this [example of how to programmatically authenticate](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/authenticating-to-asp-net-membership-provider-programmatically/).

Comment: Yes Crowcoder, I've the Control of the WebService. Let me understand and learn the URL you sent me, unless you have a better example ;) . Thanks !

Comment: @Crowcoder Hi again ! there is no another way to do it ? I just would like to know, because I dont really wnat to add other pages in my website...

Comment: @FrenchyBoss you could probably craft the proper POST to your existing login page, there are many examples of that on the web. I personally think using a dedicated service, such as an .asmx page, is cleaner, easier and less fragile.

Comment: @Crowcoder Hi again ! I m trying now to use the WebClient method, I've found some examples on the internet... The problem is I still can't do it, I even tried the HTTPWebRequest method (using POST and take care of the ViewState,etc...) and I still have errors... what do you thing I'm doing wrong ? if you wnat to check my code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071820/c-sharp-webclient-formsauthentication Thanks !