# C# WebClient FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication

EDIT: At the bottom .

I've this site which uses a WebService. 
Authentication is enabled using this way : 
"[How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx)".

I've a WinForms application who cant connect to the WebService (because this one needs an authentication).
There is an example how to perform this authentication between the WebService and the WinForms ? I heard about System.Net.HttpWebRequest, but I didn't find an example to use it .

```
class CookieWebClient : WebClient
{
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This will instanciate an internal CookieContainer.
        /// </summary>
        public CookieWebClient()
        {
            this.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use this if you want to control the CookieContainer outside this class.
        /// </summary>
        public CookieWebClient(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
        {
            this.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request == null) return base.GetWebRequest(address);
            request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
            return request;
        }
}
```

and when I want to authenticate myself :

```
using (var client = new CookieWebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "UserEmail.Text", "Administrator" },
        { "UserPass.Text", "admin" },
    };
    client.UploadValues("http://localhost:54787/logon.aspx", values);

    // If the previous call succeeded we now have a valid authentication cookie
    // so we could download the protected page
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:54787/MyWantedPage.aspx");
}
```

The problem is maybe, that I don't really put the right user and password (Administrator/admin) in the right field on the Logon.aspx... (UserMail and UserPass).

What do you thing ? (of course I assume is easier to use WebClient class.. ) 
(If I really got it, NetworkCredentials is only available with Windows Authentication and Basic Authenticaiton isnt ? I've in my side, FormsAuthentication - the same one on the URL I gave)

EDIT :

OK, I saw here :

http://odetocode.com/articles/162.aspx

And so, I also tried to perform the HTTPWebRequest saw it on the page.

I get this error when closing the response :

```
webRequest.GetResponse().Close();
```

the error is below :

```
System.Net.WebException: Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (500) Erreur interne du serveur.
```

à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Apparently there is really a problem with my WebClient POST request and my HTTPWebRequest, may be something to configure on the IIS server ?

Thanks again the community !

Comment: So you've already tried sending a HttpWebRequest? Did you try adding NetworkCredentials to its Credentials property?

Comment: @GrawCube I've tired this : (see EDIT)

Comment: ok, do anybody have an answer ? :D

Comment: Nobody has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't really find an answer about that.

The way I do it is : protect all the Web pages using Forms Authentication.
But not protect the Service I wnat to consume... (because yes, that was the goal of all of this ! )

Thank you very much anyway to all of you.